# CSS Background "cover" not showing correctly after page reload

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put a image background in a fullscreen div.

What's working:

1. load the code in a browser
2. reload the page
3. the background should display correctly

The problem:

1. load the code in a `Chrome` browser
2. **make sure the page is scrolled down**
3. reload the page
4. the background is mangled

I would not using the `<html>` tag as I need to swap the background and do animations which would corrupt the html.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>
    html, body, #background { height:100%; margin:0px; }

    #background{
        width:100%;
        top: 0;
        position: fixed;
        background: url(http://lorempixel.com/400/200/sports/) no-repeat center center #fc0;
        background-size: cover;
        background-attachment: fixed;
        z-index: -1;
    }

    #content { background: #0cf; width:400px; height:2000px; margin: 0 auto; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="background"></div>
  <div id="content">The content</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Please note I'm not using `JSfiddle` as to test this behaviour we actually need to reload the page.

Here's some images, sorry for the delay in my reply!

1) Here is what happens when I first load the page

[image: When I first load the page]

2) When I scroll down

[image: When I scroll down]

3) If, while my scrollbar is down, I reload the page I get this!

[image: On page reload]

Comment: what do you mean by mangled? seems to be working in chrome for me [your code live](http://mtctinc.com/stack.html)

Comment: perhaps by mangled you mean pixellated-to-death... this is an image size/resolution problem... not a code problem.

Comment: Thank you @Chris, I've update my post with some screenshots.

Comment: @Phlume unfortunately it happens regardless the image resolution, but if the image is really big and I reload the page I see the image half cutted. Possibly I have some bug on my chrome version? It's Version 34.0.1847.137. It's working fine in Firefox.

Comment: therre is something wrong with your chrome.  that doesn't happen in my chrome browser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background image is distorted by default as the background image is very small `400 x 200 px`.

I don't see any difference when reloading the page except that the image is changing.

Have a better resolution image to avoid distortion in bigger screens

[image]

Comment: Hello @mohamedrias, unfortunately it happens regardless the image resolution, I'm thinking it's a bug on Chrome..

Comment: No. check this http://jsbin.com/fegiq/1 Even if you scrolldown and reload the page it will be loaded.

Comment: updated image in the answer. You can see that the scrollbar is at the bottom, when i refresh i get the image

Comment: Thank you @mohamedrias, basically I only have some problems in my browser.